# Soma de Categoria e SubCategoria com PHP e MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, select, relatório, dados-hierárquicos

Já quebrei a cabeça e estou perdido em como achar a solução para meu problema, estou desenvolvendo um relatório financeiro que tem categorias e subcategoria (7 níveis)
Abaixo a estrutura de parte da minha tabela e como é alguns dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O relatório funciona "quase" corretamente, mas esse "quase" tá me atormentando, como faço para somar o níveis. Ao fazer o relatório só consigo somar onde recebeu a informação.

DICOR--->Receitas de Capital-->Aumento do Patrimônio-->Aportes do Tesouro

Só tenho lançamento de "Aportes do tesouro" como faço para a consulta ir somando do nível mais baixo para o nível mais alto.

```
insira o código aqui


//pega empenhos
mysql_select_db($database_codfor, $codfor);
$query_sql_empenho = "SELECT num_nivel, lancamento, categoria.num_categoria, categoria.des_categoria, (SELECT SUM(val_aprovado) FROM aprovado, categoria cat1 WHERE cat1.seq_categoria = aprovado.seq_categoria AND cat1.seq_categoria = categoria.seq_categoria AND YEAR(aprovado.dt_aprovado) = YEAR('".$ano."-01-01') GROUP BY cat1.seq_categoria) as val_aprovado, (SELECT SUM(empenho.val_empenho) FROM empenho, categoria cat2 WHERE cat2.seq_categoria = empenho.seq_categoria AND cat2.seq_categoria = categoria.seq_categoria AND MONTH(empenho.dt_empenho) = MONTH('".$ano."-".$mes."-01') AND YEAR(empenho.dt_empenho) = YEAR('".$ano."-01-01') GROUP BY cat2.seq_categoria) as val_empenho_no_mes, (SELECT SUM(empenho.val_empenho) FROM empenho, categoria cat3 WHERE cat3.seq_categoria = empenho.seq_categoria AND cat3.seq_categoria = categoria.seq_categoria AND YEAR(empenho.dt_empenho) = YEAR('".$ano."-01-01') AND MONTH(empenho.dt_empenho) <= MONTH('".$ano."-".$mes."-01')  GROUP BY cat3.seq_categoria) as val_empenho_no_ano, (SELECT SUM(empenho.val_empenho) FROM empenho, categoria cat4 WHERE cat4.seq_categoria = empenho.seq_categoria AND cat4.seq_categoria = categoria.seq_categoria AND YEAR(empenho.dt_empenho) = YEAR('".$ano."-01-01') AND MONTH(empenho.dt_empenho) < MONTH('".$ano."-".$mes."-01') GROUP BY cat4.seq_categoria) as val_empenho_ate_mes FROM categoria WHERE num_categoria LIKE '2%' ORDER BY categoria.num_categoria ASC";
$sql_empenho = mysql_query($query_sql_empenho, $codfor) or die(mysql_error());
$row_sql_empenho = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_empenho);
$totalRows_sql_empenho = mysql_num_rows($sql_empenho);
```

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue um exemplo, de como funciona o relatório hoje. Tenho que no meu sistema gerar um relatório similar.

Segue os códigos fontes que estou utilizando: [link] (drive.google.com/open?id=1OCRb_eaHGeLwO1N-QwY6lobbvBbaXOo8) . Nesta pasta tem os seguintes arquivos: categoria_lh.pdf - Relatório das Categorias / categoria_lh.php - Relatório das Categorias (Código Fonte) / categoria.sql - Código SQL da criação e dos dados da tabela Categoria / Empenho_l_mesXXXXXXX.pdf - Relatório de Empenhos no Mês (Esse é o "cabra" que eu quero fazer funcionar) / Empenho_l_mesXXXXXXX.php - Código Fonte do Relatório de Empenho "cabra". Agradeço a atenção de todos!!!! Um grande abraço.

Answer (score 0):

Faz a soma na query com o SUM

Exemplo:

```
mysql_query("SELECT SUM(Value) as total FROM Codes");
```

ou no php:

```
$result += $soma;
```

Comment: O problema é que a soma é para cima e não para baixo, poderia fazer como se fosse um contador (n = n + 1), mas a soma vez primeiro e depois aparece os dados.

Comment: Você já resolveu?

Comment: Nada, não sei o que fazer. O esquema é similar a contas de contabilidade vejo muito isso em aplicações desktop, mas na web vi alguns casos mas em jsp. No PHP não sei o que fazer. Seria assim.

Comment: é que eu não estou entendendo sua lógica... Calma ai...

Comment: Você postou print de outras coisas e nada do que faz na query, então pode ser que algum comando da query esteja com a sintaxe errada tenta fazer, todos separados e veja se resolve seu problema, pq o certo seria isso...

Comment: Olá, estou enviando alguns arquivos para conhecimento melhor da situação:  [link] (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OCRb_eaHGeLwO1N-QwY6lobbvBbaXOo8) . Nesta pasta tem os seguintes arquivos: categoria_lh.pdf - Relatório das Categorias / categoria_lh.php - Relatório das Categorias (Código Fonte) / categoria.sql - Código SQL da criação e dos dados da tabela Categoria / Empenho_l_mesXXXXXXX.pdf - Relatório de Empenhos no Mês (Esse é o "cabra" que eu quero fazer funcionar) / Empenho_l_mesXXXXXXX.php - Código Fonte do Relatório de Empenho "cabra".  Agradeço a atenção de todos!!!! Um grande abraço.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, acho que entendi seu problema, eu faço algo parecido aqui, talvez pode te ajudar.

Primeiro eu pego os valores com um while, depois uso um array. Você pode fazer a mesma coisa com o seu select, atribui cada valor da soma a uma variável e faz o teste se ela é nulo ou não e pode por um echo para mostrar os valores que passam. 
Acredito que vai resolver o seu problema o/

```
while (($array = oci_fetch_array($stmt, OCI_BOTH)) != false) {

        $nroempresa = $array["NROEMPRESA"];
        $nomereduzido = $array["NOMEREDUZIDO"];
        $porcentagem = $array["PORCENTAGEM"];

  }      

        $mediaQualidade = $porcentagem; //os outros medias são iguais...



    $aux = array ($mediaQualidade ,$mediaSupervisores ,$mediaProcessos,$mediaDpp);//aqui eu pego os valores que filtrei com o select
    $valores = array();

 //aqui você procura pelos valores nulos e percorre cada posição do vetor
     for($i=0 ; $i < count($aux);$i++)
                                  {
   //Nesse IF você pega apenas os valores que não são NULL ou seja 0
     if($aux[$i] != 0)
     {
          $valores[$i] = $aux[$i]; // VOCÊ PODE POR UM ECHO AQUI, ELE VAI LISTAR OS VALORES QUE PASSAM.
     }
  }
 //A partir dai basta você utilizar a função array_sum que vai somar todos os itens do array $valores e dividir por 4
 $divisor = count ($valores); // essa parte você não utiliza :)
 $mediaTotal = ((array_sum($valores))/$divisor) ; // aqui a soma que você precisa com os valores usados.
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver a situação usando um pouco de lógica.

Exemplo:
Categoria 1 = 2.000.000.000 => Soma das Categorias 2 a 7
Categoria 2 = 2.100.000.000 => Soma das Categorias 3 a 7
Categoria 3 = 2.110.000.000 => Soma das Categorias 4 a 7
Categoria 4 = 2.111.000.000 => Soma das Categorias 5 a 7
Categoria 5 = 2.111.100.000 => Soma das Categorias 6 a 7
Categoria 6 = 2.111.110.000 => Soma da  Categoria 7
Categoria 7 = 2.111.111.000 => Dado
....

```
Código Inicial:
//pega categorias
mysql_select_db($database_codfor, $codfor);
$query_sql_categorias = "SELECT categoria.num_nivel, categoria.lancamento, categoria.num_categoria, categoria.des_categoria, categoria.seq_categoria FROM categoria WHERE num_categoria LIKE '2%' ORDER BY categoria.num_categoria ASC";
$sql_categorias = mysql_query($query_sql_categorias, $codfor) or die(mysql_error());
$row_sql_categorias = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_categorias);
$totalRows_sql_categorias = mysql_num_rows($sql_categorias);
```

do {

```
$nivel = $row_sql_categorias['num_nivel'];

echo '<tr ';
  if ($row_sql_empenho['lancamento'] == 'S') { echo 'bgcolor="#F1F1F1"'; }  
echo ' >';
echo '  <td class="texto">';

  if ($nivel == 1 ){
      echo '<b> ';
  }
  if ($nivel == 2 ){
      echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp';
  }  
  if ($nivel == 3 ){
      echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp';
  }  
  if ($nivel == 4 ){
      echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp';
  } 
  if ($nivel == 5 ){
      echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp';
  } 
  if ($nivel == 6 ){
      echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp';
  } 
  if ($nivel == 7 ){
      echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp';
  } 

  $array = str_split($row_sql_categorias['num_categoria'], 1);

  echo $array[0].".".$array[1].$array[2].$array[3].".".$array[4].$array[5].$array[6].".".$array[7].$array[8].$array[9]; 
  echo ' - '.$row_sql_categorias['des_categoria'];

  if ($nivel == 1 ){
      echo '</b>';
  } 

echo '</td>';   

$categoria = $row_sql_categorias['num_categoria'];

$rest9     = substr($categoria, 1); /// 2000000000 => 000000000
$rest8     = substr($categoria, 2); /// 2000000000 => 00000000
$rest7     = substr($categoria, 3); /// 2000000000 => 0000000
$rest6     = substr($categoria, 4); /// 2000000000 => 000000
$rest5     = substr($categoria, 5); /// 2000000000 => 00000
$rest4     = substr($categoria, 6); /// 2000000000 => 0000
$rest3     = substr($categoria, 7); /// 2000000000 => 000
$rest2     = substr($categoria, 8); /// 2000000000 => 00
$rest1     = substr($categoria, 9); /// 2000000000 => 0

if     ($rest9 == '000000000') { $categoria_final = substr($categoria, 0, 1); } /// 2
elseif ($rest8 == '00000000')  { $categoria_final = substr($categoria, 0, 2); } /// 20
elseif ($rest7 == '0000000')   { $categoria_final = substr($categoria, 0, 3); } /// 200
elseif ($rest6 == '000000')    { $categoria_final = substr($categoria, 0, 4); } /// 2000
elseif ($rest5 == '00000')     { $categoria_final = substr($categoria, 0, 5); } /// 20000
elseif ($rest4 == '0000')      { $categoria_final = substr($categoria, 0, 6); } /// 200000
elseif ($rest3 == '000')       { $categoria_final = substr($categoria, 0, 7); } /// 2000000
elseif ($rest2 == '00')        { $categoria_final = substr($categoria, 0, 8); } /// 20000000
elseif ($rest1 == '0')         { $categoria_final = substr($categoria, 0, 9); } /// 200000000

/// Aprovado

mysql_select_db($database_codfor, $codfor);
$query_sql_aprovado = "SELECT SUM(val_aprovado) as val_aprovado FROM aprovado, categoria WHERE categoria.seq_categoria = aprovado.seq_categoria AND categoria.num_categoria LIKE  '".$categoria_final."%' AND YEAR(aprovado.dt_aprovado) = YEAR('".$ano."-01-01') GROUP BY categoria.seq_categoria";
$sql_aprovado = mysql_query($query_sql_aprovado, $codfor) or die(mysql_error());
$row_sql_aprovado = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_aprovado);
$totalRows_sql_aprovado = mysql_num_rows($sql_aprovado);

$val_aprovado = $row_sql_aprovado['val_aprovado'];

echo '  <td class="numero">';
if ($val_aprovado != 0) { echo number_format($val_aprovado,2,",","."); }
echo '</td>';

/// Emprenho Até o mês    

mysql_select_db($database_codfor, $codfor);
$query_sql_empenho_ate_mes = "SELECT SUM(empenho.val_empenho) as val_empenho_ate_mes FROM empenho, categoria WHERE categoria.seq_categoria = empenho.seq_categoria AND categoria.num_categoria LIKE  '".$categoria_final."%' AND MONTH(empenho.dt_empenho) < MONTH('".$ano."-".$mes."-01') AND YEAR(empenho.dt_empenho) = YEAR('".$ano."-01-01') GROUP BY categoria.seq_categoria";
$sql_empenho_ate_mes = mysql_query($query_sql_empenho_ate_mes, $codfor) or die(mysql_error());
$row_sql_empenho_ate_mes = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_empenho_ate_mes);
$totalRows_sql_empenho_ate_mes = mysql_num_rows($sql_empenho_ate_mes);

$val_empenho_ate_mes = $row_sql_empenho_ate_mes['val_empenho_ate_mes'];

echo '  <td class="numero">';
if ($val_empenho_ate_mes != 0) { echo number_format($val_empenho_ate_mes,2,",","."); }
echo '</td>';

/// Emprenho No mês 
mysql_select_db($database_codfor, $codfor);
$query_sql_empenho_no_mes = "SELECT SUM(empenho.val_empenho) as val_empenho_no_mes FROM empenho, categoria WHERE categoria.seq_categoria = empenho.seq_categoria AND categoria.num_categoria LIKE  '".$categoria_final."%' AND MONTH(empenho.dt_empenho) = MONTH('".$ano."-".$mes."-01') AND YEAR(empenho.dt_empenho) = YEAR('".$ano."-01-01') GROUP BY categoria.seq_categoria";
$sql_empenho_no_mes = mysql_query($query_sql_empenho_no_mes, $codfor) or die(mysql_error());
$row_sql_empenho_no_mes = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_empenho_no_mes);
$totalRows_sql_empenho_no_mes = mysql_num_rows($sql_empenho_no_mes);

$val_empenho_no_mes = $row_sql_empenho_no_mes['val_empenho_no_mes'];

echo '  <td class="numero">';
if ($val_empenho_no_mes != 0) { echo number_format($val_empenho_no_mes,2,",","."); }
echo '</td>';


/// Emprenho No Ano 
mysql_select_db($database_codfor, $codfor);
$query_sql_empenho_no_ano = "SELECT SUM(empenho.val_empenho) as val_empenho_no_ano FROM empenho, categoria WHERE categoria.seq_categoria = empenho.seq_categoria AND categoria.num_categoria LIKE  '".$categoria_final."%' AND YEAR(empenho.dt_empenho) = YEAR('".$ano."-01-01') GROUP BY categoria.seq_categoria";
$sql_empenho_no_ano = mysql_query($query_sql_empenho_no_ano, $codfor) or die(mysql_error());
$row_sql_empenho_no_ano = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_empenho_no_ano);
$totalRows_sql_empenho_no_ano = mysql_num_rows($sql_empenho_no_ano);

$val_empenho_no_ano = $row_sql_empenho_no_ano['val_empenho_no_ano'];

echo '  <td class="numero">';
if ($val_empenho_no_ano != 0) { echo number_format($val_empenho_no_ano,2,",","."); }
echo '</td>';


$saldo_corrente = $val_aprovado - $val_empenho_no_ano ;   
echo '</td>';
echo '  <td class="numero">'.number_format($saldo_corrente,2,",",".").'</td>';
echo '</tr>';

}
while ($row_sql_categorias = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_categorias));
?>
```